# Module not Found when launching .pyc file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pip, python-venv

Hi I generated a pyc with python -m compileall file.py
The program works in Pycharm and pandas is installed in venv but when I launch the pyc without the venv interpretor or on another machine it says Module not Found.
Panda module is found when I install pandas outside the venv.

Do I have to do pip install all modules on every environment or is there a way for the .pyc to work without installing modules on the host ?
[project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLwUQ.png)

$ python PXAGIRA01.cpython-37.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "_SOURCES/PXAGIRA01.py", line 4, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: Yes you need to install all modules in every environment. Can you clarify why you need to do this? Perhaps there is a good solution for you.

Comment: Thank you @jkr
My colleague needs to launch the .pyc on a Windows server and he knows nothing about Python or venv

Comment: Ok. You can consider "freezing" your python app: see https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/. Another option is to help your colleague use python on their windows server.